# Schnorr Fiat Shamir Transformation

Tags: cryptography, schnorr-signatures

In the Schnorr identity protocol, we can transform the interactive ZKP into a non-interactive one by replacing the role of the verifier (i.e. providing a random challenge value) with a hash function that uses the prover's encrypted nonce as input.

```
s = r + e*x

where: 
e = H(r*G)
```

Validation works by ensuring:

```
sG== R + e*P

where:
R = r*G
```

Assume that in this non-interactive model, the prover picks an `r` value **in advance**, and runs `R` through the hash function to determine its  corresponding `e` digest. Assume the prover is malicious, and is looking to trick a verifier into accepting a Schnorr signature without knowing the private key `x`. If the prover resuses this `e` value when constructing the signature, while also selecting an arbitrary `s` value,they could back out `sG = rG-eP`. Since the prover knows R, e and P, it seems as if they could convince a verifier that the signature is valid, without needing knowledge of the private key. What prevents this from happening?

Comment: Two comments: in a Schnorr signature (rather than just an identification attempt), a message is also included in the hash (so `e = H(rG||msg)`). Second, the uppercase letters in your protocol represent group elements in which the discrete logarithm problem is hard, so you can't solve `sG = rG-eP` for `s` (as that would require "dividing" by G, which is computationally infeasible).

Comment: So basically it would be impossible to find an `s` value that balances, b/c `sG=rG-eP --->  sG=rG-e*xG`. Dividing out G leaves us with `s=r+e*x` which requires knowledge of `x`?

Comment: Exactly. You can write it as `s = r - e*(P/G)`, but the `P/G` part can't be computed.